# jenkins exception while git tag

Tags: git, jenkins, github, jenkins-plugins

We are getting an error in Jenkins job when git is trying to tag the repo, below is the detail of the exception we are getting.

Below is the version we have on the Jenkins box:
1. Jenkins - 1.640
2. git plugin - 1.5.0
3. git-client plugin - 1.18.0

Does anyone have any thoughts over the same on how to resolve the issue?

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #66
>   jenkins-testrepo-bug70693-66 # timeout=10
>       FATAL: null
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at hudson.plugins.git.util.Build.getSHA1(Build.java:32)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.computeChangeLog(GitSCM.java:1292)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.access$1300(GitSCM.java:58)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1257)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1211)
>           at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2719)
>           at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:120)
>           at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
>           at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
>           at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:62)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>           at ......remote call to ruby2_windows_vpc (i-0fc07287f0072101f)(Native Method)
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
>           at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:220)
>           at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:781)
>           at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:979)
>           at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
>           at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1211)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:607)
>           at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
>           at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
>           at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
>           at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>           at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>           at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
>       Archiving artifacts
>       Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I was able to find out this post https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/279, but still not able to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try using SSH protocol to clone GIT repository. Seems communication with git not working for you via Http protocol.